# Passing a list to another component through Link in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a list categoriesSelected to a new component through a Link. Then in that new component, all I want to do is console.log the categoriesSelected but right now it is returning as undefined. Here is the Link:

```
<Link to={{
      pathname: "/input-data", state: {
      data: categoriesSelected
      }
      }} className="link">
      <Button size="lg" id="continue">
      Continue
      </Button>
      </Link>
```

And here is how I try to console log it in the other component:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        const { data } = this.props.location.state
    }

    render() {

        const Category = () => { console.log(this.data); return null};

        return (
            <div>
                <Container className="login text-secondary">
                    <Form className="form text-left">
                        <Col className="dropdown">
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Category />
                            </FormGroup>

                               ...
```

Comment: if you try to `console.log(this.props.location.state)` in `componentDidMount` it work?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than accessing the data in `componentDidMount`, why not just use the prop directly in the `<Category/>` and store at as an instance "method"?

For example:

```
class Component extends React.Component {

    Category = () => {
        console.log(this.props.location.state.data)
        return null
    }

    render() {
        const {Category} = this

        return (
           <Category /> 
        )
    }

}
```